# Ant depends attribute leading to errant behavior

Tags: ant

I have two Ant tasks. If I run them, one after the other, from the command line -- no problems.

But if I include them in the [depends](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html#targets) attribute of another task like this `depends='taskA,taskB'` I get errant results.

Are the depends being run in series instead of in sequence?  Without going into the specifics of the ant tasks -- any ideas?

Comment: They are run in sequence.  To get a useful answer, you are going to have to share more about what isn't happening as expected.  How about adding an echo to your three Ant tasks and commenting on the order/output?

Answer (score 0):

ANT only executes dependent tasks once... The example below illustrates this strange behaviour.

This falls into the category of feature rather than bug. It's just the way ANT works. The thing to bear in mind is that ANT is not designed as a procedural programming language.

If your sub task is procedural in nature it would be best invoked as a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) (or better again create a re-usable [antlib](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html) of build functions).

## Example

```
$ ant
Buildfile: /path/to/my/home/build.xml

subtask1:
     [echo] hello world

subtask2:
     [echo] hello world

build1:
     [echo] hello world

build2:
     [echo] hello world

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

   <target name="build" depends="build1,build2"/>

   <target name="build1" depends="subtask1,subtask2">
      <echo message="hello world"/>
   </target>

   <target name="build2" depends="subtask1,subtask2">
      <echo message="hello world"/>
   </target>

   <target name="subtask1">
      <echo message="hello world"/>
   </target>

   <target name="subtask2">
      <echo message="hello world"/>
   </target>

</project>
```